# AVG of Values except 0 (except 0 is only value) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to have AVG excluding 0s from a list of values that can contain them, except in the case that 0 is the only values available (or at least there's just one row and the values is exactly 0).

At the moment I use

```
SELECT AVG (NULLIF(feature, 0)) 
from cluster_density_feat 
where cluster_id=1;
```

but it returns NULL if feature value cluster_id has only one row and his feature values is 0 or if every row of this cluster_id has only zero values.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVG()` uses all the values from the group, it cannot exclude the `0`s. You should exclude them using a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT IFNULL(AVG(feature), 0)
FROM cluster_density_feat 
WHERE cluster_id = 1
   AND feature <> 0
```

If all the values in the `feature` column are `0`, the `feature <> 0` condition produces an empty set of rows and `AVG()` returns `NULL`. The function `IFNULL()` returns its second argument when the first one is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a WHERE clause to exclude the 0 values, and if you want to get 0 if there are no other values than 0 use coalesce to get 0, COALESCE is a function that will either get the first value between the brackets if it's not NULL and will return the second value if the first one is NULL

```
SELECT COALESCE(AVG(feature),0) 
from cluster_density_feat 
where cluster_id=1
AND NOT feature = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include feature when it is 0.

```
SELECT AVG(feature)
FROM cluster_density_feat 
WHERE cluster_id = 1
AND feature != 0;
```